# How to open FileDialog on top of all windows

Tags: java, macos, filedialog

I have a Java Swings App in which I open File Browser Dialog.

For Windows, I am using JFileChooser and JDialog but using these in MAC hangs the app so I use FileDialog for MAC.

This is the code I am using:

```
        Frame frame = null;
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame, "Select Cover Photo", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setFilenameFilter((File dir, String name) -> name.endsWith(".jpg"));
        fd.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        fd.setVisible(true);
        String filename = new File(fd.getDirectory(), fd.getFile()).getAbsolutePath();
```

This works fine in MAC also but only if I keep any browser open, it opens behind it and not on top of it.

Using Frame not as null also doesn't help.

So how can I open it on top of all opened Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why using a ***JFileChooser*** should hang your application when used on a MAC...it shouldn't but then again I've read that Swing *can* do strange things on a MACs due to the EDT. I can't personally confirm that however since I've never worked on a MAC.

One solution might be to run the dialog in a separate thread thus allowing the JFileChooser to function independently from the EDT and therefore not posing any threat to it.

As for your File Chooser dialog hiding behind your Swing application, I think it may be because of the fact that your application's JFrame is set to be **Always-On-Top** and even though the FileChooser dialog is considered modal (which it is) doesn't mean that it will be displayed above everything if **null** is used as its Parent component. The parent itself for the dialog should also be set to be Always-On-Top as well. This is usually the case regardless of what Operating System a dialog is displayed in. The following code should work regardless of what the JFileChooser or JOptionPane (, etc) dialog might be for a parent or if there is in fact no parent at all:

```
final JFrame iFRAME = new JFrame();
iFRAME.setAlwaysOnTop(true);    // ****
iFRAME.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
iFRAME.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
iFRAME.requestFocus();

JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(iFRAME);
iFRAME.dispose();
if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
    // Display selected file in console
    System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
else {
    System.out.println("No File Selected!");
}
```

And for the fact that your application crashes when run in a MAC you might want to try this:

```
final JFrame iFRAME = new JFrame();
iFRAME.setAlwaysOnTop(true);    // ****
iFRAME.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
iFRAME.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
iFRAME.requestFocus();

EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(iFRAME);   // ****
        iFRAME.dispose();
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            // Display selected file in console
            System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No File Selected!");
        }
    }
});
```